# Excel VBA - Color duplicate ranges with different colors

Tags: vba, excel, colors, duplicates

I have recurring tasks to do on big excel files at work and decided to use VBA for the first time to make my life easier.
I found a code on internet, modified and adapted it to my own sheet and it works fine.

I have a column of IDs and I need to find the ranges of duplicates ID and group them. So far I did that manually and it took ages. This code effectively colors the duplicate ranges but it doesn't switch to a different color every time a new range appears.

So let's say I have this :
001
001
001
002
002

It will color the 001 in blue, and will color 002 in blue too. Not always but it happens and I don't want that.

Here is the code :

```
    Sub ColourDuplicates()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cel As Range
Dim Cel2 As Range
Dim Colour As Long


Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Colour = 6
For Each Cel In Rng


If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Cel) > 1 And Cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
Set Cel2 = Rng.Find(Cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not Cel2 Is Nothing Then
        Firstaddress = Cel2.Address
        Do
        Cel.Interior.Color = Colour
        Cel2.Interior.Color = Colour
            Set Cel2 = Rng.FindNext(Cel2)

        Loop While Firstaddress <> Cel2.Address
    End If


Colour = Colour + 1

End If
Next

End Sub
```

So, is it possible to make it change to a different color each time a new set of values appear ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to explore a "Worksheet_OnChange" ? If it is purely manual, it will do the job nicely